# EntityException was unhandled by the user code, Underlying provider failed an open

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

1. In my mvc 4 project I have installed entity framework through nuget package manager
2. Then added EmployeeContext.cs class file to the models folder then added the following code in to that

   public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
   {
   public DbSet Employees {get; set;}
   }

and I added namespace `using System.Data.Entity;`
3. Now I added a connection string in to the web.config file, in the root directory:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="EmployeeContext" 
        connectionString="server=.; database=Sample; integrated security=SSPI"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

4. Mapped "Employee" model class to the database table, tblEmployee using "Table" attribute as shown below.

```
    [Table("tblEmployee")]  
    public class Employee  
    {  
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }  
        public string Name { get; set; }  
        public string Gender { get; set; }  
        public string City { get; set; }   
    }
```

and added the namespace "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema" for the table attribute.
5. I created EmployeeController.cs in which the ActionMethod Details() is shown below:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id) 
{  
    EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();  
    Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(x => x.EmployeeId == id);  

    return View(employee);  
}
```

6. Finally, the following code in Application_Start() function, in Global.asax file.
`Database.SetInitializer<MVCDemo.Models.EmployeeContext>(null);`
 and added the namespace `using System.Data.Entity;`

when I build this project it is showing build succeeded and run this program `http://localhost/MVC4Demo/Employee/Details/1`
I am getting error in this particular line saying that

```
Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(x => x.EmployeeId == id);    

EntityException was unhandled by the user code  
Underlying provider failed an open
```

When I install the entity framework from nugget it has the latest version 6.0.2 what is that I am doing wrong so that I am not able to run this project.

Comment: Make sure the connectionString is correct.

Comment: upto my knowledge whatever I presented in my code that connectionString only I have used.

Comment: Is `server=.` correct? Shouldn't you be using the server name instead of `.`?

Comment: Actually server=. is used to local server only no.

Comment: actually I have checked the sql server it is not in the local I have changed the server=QUTED004/SQLEXPRESS actual in which my db is there.

Comment: Actually the problem is in the entity framework I think so

Comment: If your db is in a remote server, make sure you have access to the server - ping it, check if that server allows remote connections, etc.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lrr66APUwBk&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v once you see this video tutorial I am doing this one from that video there you might get the perfect details.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use exact name of your Server in ConnectionString section. Copy it from SQL Server login page.
   [Server Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4AFy.png)

   ```
   <connectionStrings>
     <add name="EmployeeContext"
           connectionString="server=LAPTOP-J1IQQE3F\SQLEXPRESS; Database=sample; integrated security=True"
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
   </connectionStrings>
   ```
2. Change code in "Employee" Model class as following.

   ```
   using System;  

   using System.Collections.Generic;  

   using System.Linq;  

   using System.Web;  

   using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema; 
   using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;  

   namespace MVCDemo.Models


   {
           [Table("tblEmployees")]  /* to map tablename with our Modelclass*/


         public class EmployeeModel


           {
               [Key] //If the property is named something other than Id, 
                     //you need to add the [Key] attribute to it.
                     //Otherwise give error "Entity type has no key defined".
               public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
               public string Name { get; set; }
               public string Gender { get; set; }
               public string City { get; set; }
           }
       }
   ```